# how can i pass data using dismiss?

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have two viewControllers A B

I go A to B using performsegue
and DataPass A to B using prepare().

segue kind is Show.

```
if segue.identifier == "toWrite"{
            let vc = segue.destination as? WriteViewController
            vc?.diary = Date[Date.count-1]
            vc?.made_content = made_content
            vc?.presentIndex = Date[Date.count-1].presentIndex
            vc?.presentIndex = sendIndex
        }
```

but when I go B to A,
I want pass B Data to A

I can't do this\

Comment: use unwind segue, or use protocol/delegate pattern to communicate between view controller B and A

Comment: how can unwind segue? I can't  do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other way it’s to use protocole and delegate which is very common.

I’ll recommend you this link, to have a good start

https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/#back-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can pass A view controller instance to B, and set changes of B into A.

I think best way is unwind segue to pass data from B to A.

Kindly refer below link, which explained how to use unwind segue.

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/